# Why was my "not an answer" flag marked helpful, but the post not deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, flagging

I flagged [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/180711/how-do-i-stop-open-office-from-automatically-changing-the-date-format/355360#355360) as "not an answer":

> I had the same problem as Dan Dyer. I followed slesker's instructions and now my problem is solved.
>
> Now, to the openoffice developpers: I really appreciate your efforts creating the fantastic tool that openoffice is, but seriously, this stupid behaviour of automatically changing "1 Nov 2011" into "01/11/2011" and the option to disable it being completely hidden where you wouldn't look for it (I have been using text editors for more than 20 years and yet I spent more than an hour looking for this option and I couldn't find it), is a bit stupid. I suggest you put it where all the other automatic changes are, for example in one of the tabs under tools/autocorrect options Thanks!

It was marked as helpful, but not deleted. I don't want to be nit-picky, I wouldn't have even cared about an "invalid" flag here :)

All I'd like to know is: **What are the reasons for *not* deleting it?**

---

Let's see the content:

> I had the same problem as Dan Dyer. I followed slesker's instructions and now my problem is solved.

→ This is superfluous. We delete those all the time, and `@slesker`'s answer is accepted and upvoted five times; it does not need an additional "This really works" comment.

> Now, to the openoffice developpers: I really appreciate your efforts creating the fantastic tool that openoffice is, but seriously, this stupid behaviour […] and the option to disable it being completely hidden where you wouldn't look for it […] is a bit stupid.

→ Are we the OpenOffice developers? This sentence basically says: "It's stupid", and we gain nothing useful from this answer.

> I suggest you put it where all the other automatic changes are, for example in one of the tabs under tools/autocorrect options Thanks!

→ Again, who is being addressed? The average reader who just wants to solve the problem, or the OpenOffice developers?

Comment: It looks deleted to me... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My fault - handled the flag when I took a break off work but was still thinking about how to fix a bug haunting me<sup><sup><sup>1</sup></sup></sup>

Guess Instead of deleting, I downvoted & marked as helpful<sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup>

<sup><sup><sup>1 Note to self: When trying to figure out how to fix a compiler bug - don't moderate</sup></sup></sup>

<sup><sup><sup>2 although I could've sworn I hit the delete....</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Ah, very well then, feel free to delete this whole "bug" here :)

Comment: Same thing happened to me (helpful flag + post still there), could you please [take a look](http://superuser.com/q/566101/194694)? The question has been abandoned and cannot be answered because it lacks details. I don't think it's important enough to post a new Meta question.

Comment: @gronostaj the flag was auto-cleared because it was flagged as VLQ and since someone edited it, it's not exactly VLQ. Let me re-iterate, VLQ should be reserved **only** for unsalvageable junk. If a question doesn't have enough details, it should be flagged/closed as "unclear what you're asking"